# Magento 2 - show shipping tax cost in summary

Tags: magento2, shipping, tax

I created a new shipping method for express shipping which costs 90€. How can I show the tax costs of the selected shipping method in the tax section, is there a setting in the backend?

Cart Summary:

[image: show tax]

Comment: probably a custom module would do that

Comment: So it is not solved in the official magento?

Comment: I don't think so. have you checked already?